# Error `invalid distance too far back` when Inflate HTML gZIP content

Tags: c++, c, zlib, inflate

I want to inflate HTML webpages. I am using zlib functions
`inflateInit2(&zstream,15+32);`
and then
`inflate(&zstream,Z_SYNC_FLUSH);`

It works for lots of webpages correctly but for "www.tabnak.ir" it does not work correctly.
`invalid distance too far back` is the ERROR I got for this website.
This webpage is also gzip and utf8.
 How should I deal with that?

This is For Bing.com which works Fine

```
1f 8b 08 00    ef 8c 77 56    00 ff ec 5a    eb 73 9c 46
12 ff 9e aa    fc 0f 04 d5    9d ad 78 1f    c0 3e b4 0b
96 52 b2 24    2b ba 73 1c    9d 2d 27 b9    8a af b6 06
```

This is For tabnak.ir which results in `invalid distance too far back` Error

```
1f 8b 08 00    00 00 00 00    00 03 ed fd    db 73 5b d7
99 2f 8a 3e    ab ab d6 ff    30 ac ae ac    d8 3b 82 80
39 71 a7 6d    55 39 89 7b    75 f7 4a d2    7d 92 74 af
```

Comment: The headers are [valid gzip-deflate](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt) output. As far as I know, the error you get comes from the fact that your version of zlib restrict the distance where a [back-reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE#Duplicate_string_elimination) can be looked for.

Comment: I can't tell anything from those examples, which are too short to get to the error. The examples stop partway into the first dynamic block header. Can you provide the complete streams?

Answer (score 1):

The zlib/gzip format performs compression saying things like "The next 22 bytes are the same as the 22 bytes we saw 1013 bytes ago.

In this case the record describing the repetition, is from before the size of the 'window'.

Given you have specified a maximum size of window, the likelihood, is that the data format has changed a bit, or the data you received is not the same as was sent.

Some things to check.

1. You are using the latest zlib library.
2. Standard utilities (e.g. `gunzip`, `winzip`) can decompress the data.
3. The data you are getting is not being mangled by a text filter (`'rb'` vs `'rt'`)

If that hasn't helped, try walking through the data and understanding what the failure in gzip is.

Answer (score -2):

It would seem that the file you are trying to "inflate" (decompress using zlib) is not a valid zip file. Since bing.com is most likely not a zlib file, it might be pure coincidence that you found something quite early that prevented decompression.

Comment: 0x1f8b0800 clearly looks [like a gzip-deflate compressed stream](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt)...